# onDateChanged and onCheckedChanged working together

Tags: java, android

In one activity I have a datePicker (spinner) that allows the user select their date of birth, below that the user must also select their gender. I have a button that will be enabled once both of two values have been set (date and gender). The issue that I am facing is enabling that button despite which value is changed first. Currently, the user must select their date of birth and then their gender for the button to activate. I would like the button to be enabled regardless of which values is changed first.

Here is my code:

```
final RadioGroup rGroup = findViewById(R.id.gender_radio_group);
RadioButton female_radio_button = rGroup.findViewById(rGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
RadioButton male_radio_button = rGroup.findViewById(rGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
RadioButton non_binary_radio_button = rGroup.findViewById(rGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());

//Check if datePicker and gender radiobutton has been used, if true enable button
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
datePicker_birthday.init(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
  calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), new DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

      // This overrides the radiogroup onCheckListener
      rGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
          // This will get the radiobutton that has changed in its check state
          RadioButton checkedRadioButton = group.findViewById(checkedId);
          // This puts the value (true/false) into the variable
          boolean isChecked = checkedRadioButton.isChecked();
          // If the radiobutton that has changed in check state is now checked...
          if (isChecked) {
            continue_register_birthday_gender_button.setEnabled(true);
            continue_register_birthday_gender_button.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(RegisterBirthDateAndGenderActivity.this,
              R.drawable.button_active));
          }
        }
      });

    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few issues with your code.

1. rGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener() would not be triggered if user chose the radio button selection first.
   Need to relocate outside of onDateChanged().
2. After relocation, it would not work too, as radiogroup listener does not know if datePicker entry is changed too.
3. User can choose to update gender first, followed by date or vice-versa.
   Possible solution as below:

Check out `fixme` for the comments.

```
// fixme: Add class variables (booleans) to keep track of changed ui items
  private Boolean isDatePickerOnDateChanged = false;
  private Boolean isRadioGroupOnCheckedChanged = false;

// fixme: Re-locate rGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(..) to here.
  RadioButton non_binary_radio_button = rGroup.findViewById(rGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
  rGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
      //...
      isRadioGroupOnCheckedChanged = true;
      if (isDatePickerOnDateChanged && isRadioGroupOnCheckedChanged) {
        continue_register_birthday_gender_button.setEnabled(true);
      }

// fixme: Remove previous rGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(..) inside onDateChanged() to above
  datePicker_birthday.init(... {
    @Override
    public void onDateChanged(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
      //...
      isDatePickerOnDateChanged = true;
      if (isDatePickerOnDateChanged && isRadioGroupOnCheckedChanged) {
        continue_register_birthday_gender_button.setEnabled(true);
      }
```

4. A bit of redundancy code in the above solution:

```
      isRadioGroupOnCheckedChanged = true;
      if (isDatePickerOnDateChanged && isRadioGroupOnCheckedChanged) {
        continue_register_birthday_gender_button.setEnabled(true);
      }
```

can be simplied to

```
      isRadioGroupOnCheckedChanged = true;
      if (isDatePickerOnDateChanged) {
        continue_register_birthday_gender_button.setEnabled(true);
      }
```

because `&& isRadioGroupOnCheckedChanged` is always true because of earlier statement `isRadioGroupOnCheckedChanged = true;`.

Comment: This is a little confusing, there seems to be a lot of open ended functions, would it be possible for you to edit the code so that its one complete bit?

Comment: Why would it be confusing? For (3). It's just addition of 2 boolean variables, and setting them to true when they are triggered inside the listeners, and at the same time, checking both of them (boolean variables) to see whether to enable the button or not. As for (4), it is optional.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, had to comeback to this after a little while. Your solution worked perfectly!

Comment: Glad to hear that :)